# Yii2 и обратный Relations

Tags: yii2

Есть следующие сущности:

Client
Account
AccountDomain
Domain

У аккаунта есть клиент(hasOne) и домены(hasMany)
Нужно в модельке Client получить релейшен на домены всех аккаунтов
Но так как связь у нас хранится в аккаунте, возникают сложности

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getAccountDomains() {
    return $this->hasMany(AccountDomain::className(), ['account_id' => 'account_id'])
        ->via('accounts');
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getDefaultDomains() {
    return $this->hasMany(Domain::className(), ['domain_id' => 'domain_id'])
        ->via('accountDomains');
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getAccounts() {
    return $this->hasMany(Account::className(), ['client_id' => 'client_id'])
        ->inverseOf('client');
}
```

Использую так

```
    $result = Client::find()
        ->joinWith(['defaultDomains'], true)
        ->all();
```

И получаю ошибку

> Getting unknown property: Client::account_id

Ожидается запрос вида

```
SELECT
    d.domain_name
FROM t_client c
    LEFT JOIN `t_account` a ON c.`client_id` = a.`account_id`
    LEFT JOIN `t_account_domain` ad ON a.`account_id` = ad.`account_id`
    LEFT JOIN `t_domain` d ON d.`domain_id` = ad.`domain_id` 
WHERE c.client_id = 1
```

Хотя если не тащить домены, то работает

```
    $result = Client::find()
        ->joinWith(['accountDomains'], true)
        ->all();
```

Хотя тут запрос такой же просто на один join меньше

```
SELECT
    d.domain_name
FROM t_client c
    LEFT JOIN `t_account` a ON c.`client_id` = a.`account_id`
    LEFT JOIN `t_account_domain` ad ON a.`account_id` = ad.`account_id`
WHERE c.client_id = 1
```

Ну и база

```
-- Create syntax for TABLE 't_account'
CREATE TABLE `t_account` (
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `account_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`),
  KEY `clent_id` (`client_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_t_account_t_client` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `t_client` (`client_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- Create syntax for TABLE 't_account_domain'
CREATE TABLE `t_account_domain` (
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `domain_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `domain_id` (`domain_id`),
  KEY `account_id` (`account_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_t_account_domain_t_account` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `t_account` (`account_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_t_account_domain_t_domain` FOREIGN KEY (`domain_id`) REFERENCES `t_domain` (`domain_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- Create syntax for TABLE 't_client'
CREATE TABLE `t_client` (
  `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`client_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- Create syntax for TABLE 't_domain'
CREATE TABLE `t_domain` (
  `domain_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `domain_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`domain_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Вполне очевидная ошибка, 'account_id' отсутствует в моделе Client. Не понимаю в чем вопрос, если текст ошибки дает ответ однозначный.

Comment: Верно. Поля там нет. У аккаунта есть связь на клиента а не наоборот. Но билдер некорректно строит запрос. Перечитайте вопрос еще раз

Comment: билдер некорректно строит запрос? Откуда такой вывод? Я так понимаю, Вы просто не правильно пользуетесь билдером.

Comment: Вывод оттуда, что у меня пытается найти **account_id** у клиента, а не наоборот.

Comment: Правильно, как построили, так и делает.